# PyException: ImportError: No module named domreg

Tags: android, python, xml, minidom, chaquopy

I am getting the below error while running this script (`"from xml.dom import minidom"`) from chaquopy androi application python console.

`PyException: ImportError: No module named domreg`

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug which prevented implicit relative imports from working with the import hook enabled. This has been fixed in version 0.4.4 which is available now (https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/12).