# Chaquopy Android import error

Tags: android, python, import, importerror, chaquopy

I'm getting an `ImportError: No module named six` while trying to test out Chaquopy for Android. Seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885861/pyexception-importerror-no-module-named-domreg), but according to that it should be fixed. I can see the `six.py` file in the .zip archive and I've installed six in my python distribution.

Here is the java code:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (! Python.isStarted()) {
        Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(activity));//error is here!
        myInstance = Python.getInstance();
    } else {
        myInstance = Python.getInstance();
    }

    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff here
            String tt = myInstance.toString();//placeholder
            myTextView.setText(tt);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

I've also added the relevant gradle lines and reinstalled python so it's using the default path (was using Anaconda before).

Full error output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.quant.quantshot, PID: 1188
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
{com.example.quant.quantshot/com.example.quant.quantshot.MainActivity}: 
com.chaquo.python.PyException: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "chaquopy_java.pyx", line 94, in chaquopy_java.init_module (.c:2359)
    File "java\chaquopy.pxd", line 19, in init chaquopy_java (.c:11619)
    File "/data/user/0/com.example.quant.quantshot/files/chaquopy/chaquopy.zip/java/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        from .chaquopy import *  # noqa
    File "java\import.pxi", line 1, in init java.chaquopy (.c:67298)
ImportError: No module named six
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3470)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2733)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "chaquopy_java.pyx", line 94, in chaquopy_java.init_module (.c:2359)
    File "java\chaquopy.pxd", line 19, in init chaquopy_java (.c:11619)
    File "/data/user/0/com.example.quant.quantshot/files/chaquopy/chaquopy.zip/java/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        from .chaquopy import *  # noqa
    File "java\import.pxi", line 1, in init java.chaquopy (.c:67298)
ImportError: No module named six
    at com.chaquo.python.Python.startNative(Native Method)
    at com.chaquo.python.Python.start(Python.java:48)
    at com.example.quant.quantshot.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6786)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3407)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an inadvertent dependency on `six` being built into the app. It was fixed in version 0.4.5 (https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/13).

Comment: Worked like a charm!